# Should Hibernate entities be autowired or 'manually' instantiated?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, autowired

On a Spring/Hibernate project I'm working on, I noticed that to persist a new object in the database, an autowired entity was used. Simplified, it was doing something like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeArbitraryManager {
    @Autowired private SomeArbitraryItem item; // The Hibernate entity.
    @Autowired private SomeArbitraryDao dao; // The corresponding DAO.

    public void arbitraryMethodThatNeedsToStoreAnItem(long someId, String someValue) {
        item.setPropertyA(someId);
        item.setPropertyB(someValue);
        item.setPropertyC(new Date());
        dao.save(item);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, this is the simplified idea, in practice there were more properties, different methods doing the insertion and error handling. Now, a bug occurred where Hibernate would actually just overwrite the last inserted row. I believe this was caused by the SomeArbitraryItem receiving an id (for the primary key) after Hibernate inserted it, and Hibernate assuming an update when the same item was saved. On another occasion, the inserted object's properties were not all updated, so a SomeArbitraryItem was inserted with some fields containing last insertion's values.

I asked why there wasn't just a new SomeArbitraryItem used for each insertion, like so:

```
    SomeArbitraryItem item = new SomeArbitraryItem();
    ... // Set properties.
    dao.save(item);
```

This is what would make sense to me, since if it's a new (database) object, shouldn't it also be a new regular, java, object? The answer given to me when I asked though was, that when using DI, you shouldn't be creating objects.

I've Googled to see what the policy on this is, but I can't find anything. There *are* tons of Spring/Hibernate tutorials though, and I'm not seeing the Hibernate entities being autowired in those. However, they could be simplified since they are just tutorials.

So: How should this be done? Should Hibernate entities be autowired? Should they just be instantiated? Or, in order to not tie us down to a specific class, should we fetch a new one from the Spring application context each time? Something else?

(For emphasis: I'm not looking for solutions to the side-effects of the method used. I'm asking if the principle of it is correct in view of Spring and Hibernate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only wire classes that will provide specific functionality to the current whole class. Entity classes, managed by Hibernate (or any other ORM framework), do not meet such requirement, and you should create it using `new` keyword or they will be created as result of finding data from your datasource, so they should not be managed by Spring nor any other DI framework.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes sense to me. If you happen to know of any documents to support it and could add those that would be even more appreciated. I had really hoped to get more response to this question and more votes on your comment as a confirmation, but either way it's a satisfying answer in my mind.

Comment: There are no documents. It's just experience.

Comment: I was trying to be 'proper'. Personally, I'd just take your 45.2k-reputation-word for it. ;)